# Minibatch Standard Deviation Layer

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I'm reworking some of the GANs I originally made in TensorFlow2 to see if I can improve performance in Mathematica, and have been stuck on how to create a custom **Minibatch Standard Deviation Layer**. I'm trying to implement it to stabilize the training process and reduce instances of *Mode Collapse*. (More information on its purpose (with Python) can be found [here](https://github.com/GANs-in-Action/gans-in-action/blob/master/chapter-6/Chapter_6_PGGAN.ipynb).) Basically it takes the mean of the samples and figures out the standard deviation within each batch. The generator is penalized if the standard deviation is too low.

I thought the new `FunctionLayer` in 12.2 would be useful for this purpose but this is as far as I've gotten so far. Some how I need to thread that `minibatch` layer back into the network.

```
discriminator = NetGraph[{
   ConvolutionLayer[16, 5, "Stride" -> 3, "Input" -> {3, 4000}],
   ElementwiseLayer["ELU"],
   ConvolutionLayer[32, 3, "Stride" -> 1],
   ElementwiseLayer["ELU"],
   ConvolutionLayer[64, 2, "Stride" -> 1],
   ElementwiseLayer["ELU"],
   minibatch,
   FlattenLayer[],
   100,
   Ramp,
   1,
   Tanh,
   SequenceLastLayer[]
   },
  {1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 8 -> 9 -> 10 -> 11 -> 12 -> 13, 
   6 -> 7}
]

minibatch = NetChain[{
   AggregationLayer[Mean, {2}],
   FunctionLayer[StandardDeviation]
   }]

GAN = NetInitialize@NetGANOperator[{generator, discriminator}]

BATCHSIZE = 64;
noise := RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 0.2], 400]

trained = NetTrain[
  GAN,
  <|"Sample" -> RandomSample[trainingData, BATCHSIZE], 
   "Latent" -> Table[noise, BATCHSIZE]|>,
  BatchSize -> BATCHSIZE
  ]
```

[image]

The Wolfram framework always seems to apply the whole net to one example. How can I apply a function to all samples in the round and then append it to the array? Even if it's just a reference, I'm pretty sure I can follow it through.

**Updated 2020-12-18**
Along with the bounty I have also added a 3 samples of the training data that can be seen on a [public gist](https://gist.github.com/BBirdselllab/b13de554a9e870036018a18a0cab166e) of the shape {3,300}.

**Updated 2021-01-02**
Corrected code.

Comment: It looks like your code not complete. There is a message  about it `Syntax::bktmcp: Expression "NetGraph[<<1>>" has no closing "]".`

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure this is correct, but here's my attempt - perhaps it can get you started and/or inspire others to give a more correct answer.

My understanding is that we want access to the standard deviation of some features across the batches during training. `BatchNormalizationLayer` *should* have access to this internally - even though the only exposed ports are `Input` and `Output`. In-fact the Properties & Relations section under Documentation gives us a hint, that it actually computes:

```
batchNormFunction = 
  Function[Block[{sd = Sqrt[#MovingVariance + #Epsilon]},
    (#2 * #Scaling / sd ) + (#Biases - (#Scaling * #MovingMean)/sd)]];
```

As such, I think we can (ab)use the layer to extract the batch standard deviation as follows:

```
params = <|"Scaling" -> 1, "Biases" -> 0, "MovingMean" -> 0, 
   "MovingVariance" -> mv, "Epsilon" -> 0|>;
input/batchNormFunction[params, input]

Out[84]= Sqrt[mv]
```

Note this will fail if either "MovingVariance" or the input is zero. So you probably want to add a small amount of "Biases" and "Epsilon" to stabilize it.
Here I define a 'frozen' `BatchNormalizationLayer` with no "Biases" and the default value of "Epsilon" (0.001) as follows:

```
bn = BatchNormalizationLayer["Scaling" -> 1, "Biases" -> 0, 
  "MovingMean" -> 0, "Input" -> {512, 4, 4}, 
  LearningRateMultipliers -> <|"Biases" -> 0, "MovingMean" -> 0, 
    "MovingVariance" -> 1, "Scaling" -> 0|>]
```

and define our minibatch layer using the `NetGraph`:

```
minibatch = 
 NetGraph[<|"bn" -> bn, "average" -> AggregationLayer[Mean, All], 
   "rep" -> ReplicateLayer[{1, 4, 4}], "cat" -> CatenateLayer[], 
   "divide" -> ThreadingLayer[Divide]|>, {NetPort["Input"] -> 
    "bn", {NetPort["Input"], "bn"} -> 
    "divide" -> "average" -> "rep", {NetPort["Input"], "rep"} -> 
    "cat"}]
```

[image]

Note that {512,4,4} above comes from the particular GAN I was playing around with, which I suspect will be easy enough to change. For reference here is the the GAN network - it seems to initialize properly, although I haven't trained on anything.

```
leaky = ParametricRampLayer["Slope" -> 0.2, 
   LearningRateMultipliers -> 0];
conv[channels_, kernel_] := 
 Sequence[ConvolutionLayer[channels, kernel, 
   PaddingSize -> (kernel + 1)/2 - 1], leaky]
deconv[channels_, kernel_] := 
 Sequence[DeconvolutionLayer[channels, kernel, 
   PaddingSize -> (kernel + 1)/2 - 1], leaky]
enc = NetEncoder[{"Image", {128, 128}}];
downSample[] := PoolingLayer[2, 2, "Function" -> Mean]
upSample[] := ResizeLayer[{Scaled[2], Scaled[2]}]

discriminator = 
 NetChain[{conv[16, 1], conv[16, 3], conv[32, 3], downSample[], 
   conv[32, 3], conv[64, 3], downSample[], conv[64, 3], conv[128, 3], 
   downSample[], conv[128, 3], conv[256, 3], downSample[], 
   conv[256, 3], conv[512, 3], downSample[], minibatch, conv[512, 3], 
   ConvolutionLayer[512, 4], leaky, LinearLayer[{}]}, "Input" -> enc]

generator = 
 NetChain[{DeconvolutionLayer[512, 4], leaky, deconv[512, 3], 
   upSample[], deconv[256, 3], deconv[256, 3], upSample[], 
   deconv[128, 3], deconv[128, 3], upSample[], deconv[64, 3], 
   deconv[64, 3], upSample[], deconv[32, 3], deconv[32, 3], 
   upSample[], deconv[16, 3], deconv[16, 3], 
   DeconvolutionLayer[3, 1]}, "Input" -> {512, 1, 1}]

NetInitialize[NetGANOperator[{generator, discriminator}]]
```

Comment: The timing is poor for me to try this. I've been away from the computer today and need to get in a plane first thing tomorrow. Reading through it looks like an excellent start. I appreciate the contrabution and will return to it soon..